# MobileFirst CLI 7.1 push on remote server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

I try to push .wlapp to a remote server with the following command.

mfp push rockW510_Local mprod

And i have the following error

> Preparing for push...
>   Error: error code: 306
>   Error: The runtime being pushed to [mprod] is not the same as the application's >runtime [StarterApplication_ionic-release71]
>   Error: INVALIDRUNTIMESCENARIO
>   Error: Push has failed

Is it not possible to push .wlapp, .adapter on a remote server with a different runtime of the local projet ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

The official word is as following:

> This behavior is by design.  That runtime check was put in place to
>   ensure MFP project based apps were only deployed to the associated
>   project's runtime.
>
> Cordova apps created outside of a MFP project can be deployed to any
>   runtime.

---

I was able to recreate this the following way:

1. Created a local server with a project "myproject", added a Hybrid app and mfp pushed it to create the .wlapp file
2. Create a server config for the remote server I have
3. Ran the command: mfp push server2 myproject2

It failed with the same error.
I then:

1. Loaded the console of server2
2. Dropped the .wlapp file

The .wlapp file successfully got deployed

So I guess that something in mfp push is failing in this scenario. Or it could be the expected behavior... need to double-check this (in progress...)

In the meanwhile you have the above workaround.

Comment: I've the same problem. I tried the workaround you have mentioned but it did not work for me. Do you have any update on this?